# Why does font-size only work when I set background-color on a button?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am in Rails 3.2.6, on Chrome.

I have the following code in my html.erb file:

```
<div id="beta">
    <%= form_tag({}, {:id => "id_search"}) do %>
        ID: <%= text_field_tag "beta_id" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Go" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

When I set the font-size to 24pt in my CSS file, the text field changes properly, but the button doesn't change at all.  I pulled it up in my Developer Tools, and it was getting the CSS property, but just not changing its font size.  Even when I put `!important`, nothing happened.  I couldn't change the font-family either.

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/R5CXg/

Changing other properties worked.  When I changed the `background-color` property, the button suddenly turned square instead of round, and popped into the correct font-size and font-family.

Why was this the case and how can I work around it?

Comment: Would you please create the relevant HTML/CSS code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: To alter the styles of a button you usualy have to set either a `border` or a `background-color` otherwise none of the styles will take effect.

Answer (score 2):

Try including:

```
-webkit-appearance: button;
-moz-appearance: button;
```

in your css before the font-size, and apply it to the button only, so give an id for the btn then apply the css with the code to the button.
This is to ensure webkit displays it correctly. Hopeful this will get you in the right direction.

Comment: That's how styles in browsers are. It might display normally on other browsers but if there is a problem with chrome, then you have the include the css change. Different browsers display the html differently, that cannot be helped

Comment: It's because the browsers are built differently. So the same html code will work on chrome but it might not work on IE, that's why people complain about IE that much. The same principle applies to the js and css.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons styles vary between browsers.

Webkit tries to use native controls which cannot be styled with all CSS properties. Try:

```
-webkit-appearance:none
```

To disable the special native styling. [It's a magic vendor-specific property.](http://davidwalsh.name/webkit-appearance)